# How to find and replace inside a file with some Javascript variable using Bash command

Tags: javascript, sed, terminal

I am writing some code in Javascript, and I have defined couple variables called

```
const url = "www.google.com"
const data = "xyz"
```

and I also have a text file, which looks like the following:

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: www.yahoo.com
    certificate-authority-data: abc
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: aws
  name: aws
```

All I want to do is to replace the "sever" name and "certificate-authority-data" with the variables I defined, which looks like"

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: www.google.com
    certificate-authority-data: xyz
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: aws
  name: aws
```

I read about to use

```
sed -i "s%www.yahoo.com%www.google.com%g" "test.txt"
```

However, here are two issues

1. I don't really want to refer the "www.yahoo.com" in the terminal, since the url is changed all the time, what I want is to use some regex to capture this url after "server: "
2. how can I refer the Javascript variable in the terminal?

I am really stuck in here, any helps

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is the JavaScript on the client or the server (nodejs)?  Also, would bash variables be sufficient for the sed command?

Comment: @Informagician Yes I am using nodejs. basically I just replace the variable defined in the Nodejs in the terminal

Comment: Could nodejs do the replacing?  It would need to read through the file, but it would be easier to use nodejs with its own variables.

Comment: that works, since the file is in the folder, so I thought it would be easier to do all shell command, then use shelljs to execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method of getting nodejs to execute a bash command if that is truly desired.  [NodeJS Shell Commands](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options).  In this case, it might look something like this:

```
const replaceUrl = "www.yahoo.com";
const url = "www.google.com";
const data = "xyz";
child_process.execSync('sed -i "s%' + replaceUrl + '%' + url + '%g" "test.txt"').toString();
```

I've used the synchronous version here as it is convenient, but the asynchronous version could be used with a callback.  The function returns a buffer, so the `.toString()` is to make sense of any data, but there shouldn't be any coming back in your case.

Comment: The sed command is not working for me, I think maybe it is missing a quotation mark?

Comment: that was pretty bad!  I closed the quotation mark, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

if js file is `a`, text file is `b`
try gnu sed twice, each for one replace pair ie. 2 lines followed by enter in shell, each is 2 process chained into 1

```
$ sed -En 's!^.*\burl\s*=\s*"([^"].+)"\s*!s/\\b(server:\\s*).+/\\1\1/i!;te;b;:e p;q' a |sed -i -Ef - b

$ sed -En 's!^.*\bdata\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s*!s/\\b(certificate-authority-data:\\s*).+/\\1\1/i!;te;b;:e p;q' a |sed -i -Ef - b
```

Note: test it first by disusing `-i` opt at 2nd ie. `sed -i -E..` become `sed -E...`

by one line gnu awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR {if(/(const\s)?url\s*=/) {u=gensub(/.*url.*"([^"]+)"/,"\\1",1)} else if(/(const\s)?data\s*=/) {v=gensub(/.*data.*"([^"]+)"/,"\\1",1)} next} {if(/server:/) print gensub(/(.*server:\s*).*/,"\\1"u,1); else if (/certificate\S+:/) print gensub(/(.*certificate-authority-data:\s*).*/,"\\1"v,1); else print }' a b
```